# Issue writing vlookup for filling values based on filter for data over a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, formula, vlookup

I am unable to create a proper VLOOKUP to fill B8, B9, B10 in the image attached. which are derived from the table  A12:G15, based on filter value selected in B1. could you help with a proper VLOOKUP command to solve this issue.

[image]

I tried to concatenate and add multiple cells like suresh+july, Suresh+august but this inturn increases length of table which needs to be avoided for simplicity.

Comment: If the names are in the same order, just use `=XLOOKUP(B1,B12:G12,B13:G15)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B8`

```
=INDEX($B$13:$G$15,MATCH(A8,$A$13:$A$15,0),MATCH($B$1,$B$12:$G$12,0))
```

---

Or, Formula used in cell `B8`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A8=$A$13:$A$15)*($B$1=$B$12:$G$12)*$B$13:$G$15)
```

---

Or, Use <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> with <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> function

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP($A8,$A$13:$A$15,FILTER($B$13:$G$15,$B$1=$B$12:$G$12))
```

---

Or, if you want to use <kbd>VLOOKUP( )</kbd> then

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B8`

```
=VLOOKUP($A8,$A$13:$G$15,MATCH($B$1,$A$12:$G$12,0),0)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(FILTER($B$13:$G$15,($B$12:$G$12=$B$1)),$A$13:$A$15=A8)
```

Result:

[image]